# In Perl replacement command empties the file under Windows

Tags: windows, perl, shell

I have the following command:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/pattern//" $file_name
```

When I execute it in perl script, it empties the file (I see .bak file, it wasn't empty). When I execute it in the shell, it works. What can be the problem?

The problem is under Windows, it works fine under Linux.

EDIT 1:
I tried this one too, it empties also:

```
sub replace_pattern_in_file
{
    my ($file, $pattern, $replacement) = @_;

    open my $in, "<", $file;
    unlink $file;

    open my $out, ">", $file;
    while(my $line = <$in>)
    {
        $line =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;
        print $out $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your pattern?

Comment: Re EDIT 1, That won't work on Windows since it doesn't have anonymous file.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken; that works the same on Windows and on unix systems. On either type of systems, you will only get the behaviour you described if the pattern matches every line entirely (including the newline).

```
>echo foo>file

>echo bar>>file

>echo moo>>file

>perl -pi.bak -e "s/o//" file

>type file
fo
bar
mo
```